# Store datalist eval into a variable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

is there a way to store field from a DataList?

Such as

```
string year = Eval("date");
```

I want to do manipulation on the string year, and need to store it in the variable if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Eval, I'm guessing you're doing work inside a databinding expression? If so, that's generally the wrong place to do any actual post-processing of the data, but if you must do so, you should be able to explicitly cast like so:

```
string year = (string)Eval("date")
```

Or, if the variable isn't a string type natively,

```
string year = Eval("date").ToString()
```

Better yet, add a function to your page that accepts an object parameter and does the processing like so:

```
public string DoSomething(object value)
{
    var year = value.ToString();  // or alterinately...
    var year = value as string();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
    {
        // do something to the year
        return year;
    }

    return ""; // default in case you can't process the value
}
```

Then, in your ASP.NET page, whenever you're doing the databinding...

```
 <%# DoSomething(Eval("date")) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetLabelText(Eval("date")) %>' />
```

and

```
string GetLabelText(object date)
{
   if (date != null)
   {
        ...
        // here you can cast date to appropriate type (possibly DateTime) and
        // store that in a variable, manipulate it and return a text that would be 
        // displayed by Label1
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way? is there no way to simply put it straight into a variable?

Comment: you can manipulate to some extent in line in the markup but you can't introduce a variable there.